# Mysql Query log - dropped table

Tags: mysql

I dropped a table accidentally... There is no posibilities to recover it?

Someone knows if exists some "mysql log" where are all the queries of the mysql server?

Thanks......

Comment: Recover from last backup, and if you have binary logs (`SELECT @@sql_log_bin;`), run them until the drop statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using innodb_file_per_table or myisam, in theory you could undelete the table files at OS level, depending on your file system and wether their blocks have been reused. Slim chance, I know.